# Chrome "em" font size bug

Tags: css, google-chrome

Faced a strange font-size bug in Chrome with **retina**.

If parent `.a` have `font-size: 1px` and child `.b` have sizes `width: 50em`, then we expect that actual size of `.b` will be `50px`:

```css
.a {
  font-size: 1px;
}

.b {
  width: 50em;
  height: 50em;
  border-radius: 10em;
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
  </div>
</div>
```

And it works well in Safari, Firefox and until recently in Chrome.
But in current version of Chrome `.b` will have width `300px`.

[Here's fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bzpa2L1q/2/).

We noticed that `.a` has computed font-size `6px` instead of `1px`.
Apparently, this is the cause of the problem.

Any ideas how to fix it?

macOS 10.14.3 (**retina**)
Chrome 75.0.3770.100

Comment: it has computed font size of 1px for me... where do you see that it is 6px?

Comment: @cloned do you have retina? That's what I see: https://leonardo.osnova.io/c9c53271-6d85-f640-e332-bb845510c3ff/

Comment: ah right, that may be it. Sorry :). I think this is how browsers on retina displays work. Do you need a physical width of 1 px for something? What exactly is the problem with the current behaviour?

Comment: @cloned the problem is that size of `.b` must be `50px` as expected (so it is in other browsers), but it is `300px` instead

Comment: Then set it to 50px? `width: 50px ` What do you gain by using em? 1em does not have to be 1px.

Comment: @cloned I use `em` because I have reasons. The fact that `.b` is not the right size is a bug

Comment: What if you throw `* {-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;}` at it?

Comment: @RickvanOsta no difference :( https://jsfiddle.net/56p0dbvy/

Comment: Chrome has a feature called "minimum font size". For me it's at chrome://settings/fonts. This might be your problem. The size adjust line above doesn't seem to be working anymore.

Comment: @RickvanOsta so, it means that there's no way to fix this problem outside the client side?

Comment: It would seem so. My advice would be to find some way to avoid using `em` values. Google won't fix this in a short amount of time, and even if they did, there will be a lot of people using an older Chrome version to whom your page will render incorrectly.

Comment: https://crbug.com/944002#c42 looks relevant, but the impact might be such that it requires user action to fix, and your CSS should be changed.